# Overall analysis of multiple trends of 2 variables

Tags: inference

[image]I have multiple sets of trends which show how the concentration of 2 quantities vary with respect to each other over number of observations. Each set is independent from each other and the duration between 2 observation points is not fixed. The x axis in the picture is the sequence of observation (and not any conventional unit of time); both the y axes are the concentrations of the 2 variables (which are being displayed as the labels). I want to check how the concentrations of these 2 variables differ collectively for all the sets combined.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a "trend" and an "overall" trend.  Would these be slopes (or rates)? Total changes?  How did you determine the individual "trends"?

Comment: The graphics are intriguing, but because their axes are unlabeled (and do not seem to correspond to any given "period of time"), their meanings are not explained, and the ranges of the x and coordinates vary, it is now even less clear what you are trying to ask.  Perhaps you could describe what these variables mean, how they were collected, and what you are hoping to achieve at the end of your analysis.

Comment: @whuber I've edited the description. Hope it's more clear and helpful now.

Comment: One note - since in each graph the concentrations are inversely related, you only need one line in each - the second line adds no information.

Comment: @PeterFlom Concentrations of both the quantities are not inversely related every time.  That's why I want to know some method for checking their variation, otherwise I would have used Simple Correlation and Regression